# Can't bring up swagger ui with app with swagger.yaml

Tags: go, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Been googling and stack overflowing, but can't find an example on what tools or yaml tags to use to get the swagger UI configured.

Or what URL to specify on my swagger rest app to display the UI (maybe it's already there and I don't realize it?)

This is what is working:

/docs shows all the endpoints

and

/swagger.json shows all of the JSON for the paths

The rest endpoints work

My yaml:

```
swagger: "2.0"

consumes:
  - application/io.goswagger.examples.todo-list.v1+json
info:
  description: descr
  title: My Title
  version: 1.0.0

definitions:
  message:
    type: object
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      message:
        type: string
        minLength: 1

Order:
    type: object
    properties:
      name:
        type: string
      items:
        type: array
        items:
          type: object
          properties:
            name:
              type: string
            quantity:
              type: string
            description:
              type: string
            price:
              type: string
            

 error:
    type: object
    required:
      - message
    properties:
      code:
        type: integer
        format: int64
      message:
        type: string

schemes:
 - http
 
paths:
  /version:
    get:
      description: version
      operationId: version
      tags:
        - message
      responses:
        200:
          description: standard message response
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/message"

  /health:
    get:
      description: health of service
      operationId: health
      responses:
        200:
          description: healthy service
        503:
          description: service in bad state

  /v1/orders:
    get:
      description: list 
      operationId: list
      responses:
        200:
          description: list successful
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: "#/definitions/Order"
        500:
          description: list error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/message"
        default:
          description: error
          schema:
            $ref: "#/definitions/error"

  

produces:
 - application/io.goswagger.examples.todo-list.v1+json
```

Comment: GO seems to be limited to swagger 2.0

Comment: The simplest approach is to take the static [swagger.io dist](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/tree/master/dist) edit `index.html` to point to your yaml file - and serve this directory from your go application.

Comment: Thank you, will give it a go

Comment: How to serve index.html from the GO application when the code to serve content is generated from the swagger, and I can only edit the configure_myapp_reservices.go file methods  to serve content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution proposed by colm.anseo worked, but additionally I had to modify my configure_myapp_reservices.go methods as follows:

added:

```
    func uiMiddleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            // Shortcut helpers for swagger-ui
            if r.URL.Path == "/swagger-ui" || r.URL.Path == "/api/help" {
                http.Redirect(w, r, "/swagger-ui/", http.StatusFound)
                return
            }
            // Serving ./swagger-ui/
            if strings.Index(r.URL.Path, "/swagger-ui/") == 0 {
                http.StripPrefix("/swagger-ui/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("swagger-ui"))).ServeHTTP(w, r)
                return
            }
            handler.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
    
    // and modified setupGlobalMiddleware as follows:
    
    func setupGlobalMiddleware(handler http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return uiMiddleware(handler)
    }
```

Note: added Docker commands to copy dist to /swagger-ui directory in my pod

e.g.

COPY /build/dist /swagger-ui

modified index.html in my local /build/dist directory to point to:

url: "./swagger.json",

also had to acquire swagger.json file and paste into /build/dist directory

( I could download swagger.json from http://service-route/swagger.json )